# c function acting as a pointer?

Tags: c

ive seen functions passing pointers in their parameters and they are common in dynamic use executing different functions after afew steps. However i came across this representation in a header file:

```
void *allocate_mem(u_int32_t n);
```

Any clue to how it is to be used? Is the function a pointer or does it return a pointer?

Comment: Please use `cdecl.org` whenever you have questions like this... entering `void *allocate_mem(u_int32_t)`, we get __declare `allocate_mem` as function (`u_int32_t`) returning pointer to `void`__

Comment: Also, I suggest you see §6.3.2.3.1 of the C99 standard... *A pointer to **`void`** may be converted to or  from a pointer to any incomplete or object type. A pointer to any incomplete or object type may be converted to a pointer to **`void`** and back again; the result shall compare equal to the original pointer.*

Comment: See also [malloc](http://linux.die.net/man/3/malloc)

Comment: cdecl.org => "face palm myself"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See [my comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12027278/c-function-acting-as-a-pointer#comment16051518_12027278).

Please use [cdecl.org](http://cdecl.org) whenever you have questions like this... entering `void *allocate_mem(u_int32_t)`, we get the following.

> declare `allocate_mem` as function (`u_int32_t`) returning pointer to `void`.

So, we know `allocate_mem` returns `void *`. Now, you're probably wondering why you would ever want a pointer to `void`...

§6.3.2.3.1 of the C99 standard states as follows.

> A pointer to **`void`** may be converted to or  from a pointer to any incomplete or object type. A pointer to any incomplete or object type may be converted to a pointer to **`void`** and back again; the result shall compare equal to the original pointer.

Thus you can convert the result of `allocate_mem` to fit your needs, e.g.

```
float *data = allocate_mem(1024 * sizeof(float))
```

Comment: +1 for quoting the C99 standard. Man, how so I miss working in C/C++ :(

Comment: +1, just a little nitpick for your vocabulary in the second last line: what you describe here is an (implicit) conversion and not a cast. A cast in C jargon is an "explicit conversion".

Answer (score 1):

The function returns a pointer to the new memory allocated.

The return type is a void*, the reason being that the function doesn't know what you want to use it for.

If you want to use it as an array of integers, you would cast it to an int*

eg.

```
int *p = allocate_mem(4*10);
```

The argument is the size (bytes) of memory that needs to be allocated. Therefore, allocating 40 bytes for 4-byte integers makes an array of ten 4-byte integers.

Comment: don't cast the return of allocation functions. `void*` converts to any object pointer type all by itself.

Answer (score 0):

A `void *` is a pointer to something. What it points to is not known, but the idea is for it to work as sort of a neutral pointer. A `void*` param can take any kind of pointer type. However great care needs to be taken while handling these pointers as they come with their own set of limitations. You cannot dereference a void* it has to be cast to a valid type. The same goes with applying pointer arithmetic.

Refer this discussion for more details - [C - pointers in functions and void variable type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6977499/c-pointers-in-functions-and-void-variable-type)